# MVC : Action to update only a part of the model, from a client side validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, model, drop-down-menu, client-server, client-side

This is my problem.

I have a model composed of two structures.

```
public class MyDoubleStructureModel

    {
     public    MyDoubleStructureModel(CLIENT MyClient, List<PROVIDER> MyProviders);
     CLIENT MyClient {get;private set;};
     List<PROVIDER> MyProviders {get;private set;} ;
    }
```

The two objects are loaded at the beginning of the loading of the page. 
The "MyProviders" object is filling a RenderPartial :

```
<div id="dialog">
<% Html.RenderPartial("UCProviders", Model.MyProviders); %>
<%} %>
</div>
```

On my Client form, I have a dropdownlist, that should allows the user, to update the data included in the Partial View. 
It should be updated without reloading the view.

My idea, was to call (thru JQuery for instance) a function server-side, which would update only one part of my model.

```
$("#ddlChangeProviders").change(function() {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/Client/UpdateListProvider/?provID=" + $("#ddlChangeProviders").val()
                });
```

But I dont know if it is possible to update, only a part of my model (in this case the "providers" part).

Any idea to complete my code ? Am i on the right way ? I suppose only the "server side function 'UpdateListProvider' (displaying an updated list of the Providers in a PartialView) is missing...

This is what should be on my function UpdateListProvider

```
public ActionResult UpdateListProvider(int provID)
{
    List<PROVIDER> MyProvidersInMyModel = _entities.Providers.Where(c => c.PROV_ID == provID).ToList();

    var model = new MyDoubleStructureModel(null, MyProvidersInMyModel)

    return View(model);
}
```

Thanks for your help.
(Ask me if the description is not clear enough)

Answer (score 0):

yes you can update parts of your model using jquery and with regular form post as well. now you just have to write UpdateListProvider ActionREsult and update ProviderID field of your model. you can optionally return true or false showing that data updated successfully or not

```
public ActionResult UpdateListProvider(int porvID)
{
    var model = //get model to update
    model.provID = provID
    if(Save(model))return Content("true");
    return Content("false");
}
```

in client side you can write success callback of ajax to show error or success message

```
$("#ddlChangeProviders").change(function() {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/Client/UpdateListProvider/?provID=" + $("#ddlChangeProviders").val(),
                    success:function(data)
                           {
                               if(data == 'true'){alert('updated successfully');}
                               else{alert('could not update record');}
                           }
                });
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you detail, the "var model = //Get model to update" ?

Comment: since your aim is to update a model. so when you have provID in action method you just have to fetch the model in question from db etc. and update its provID field. you can also pass a unique identifier of your model in your ajax request so you can easily get model object from db

Comment: Well, I'm going to ask differently my previous question, which seems maybe to be too simple to be true :)) : what is the line code, which can get the "current model" used (and filled) of the current form ? The 'complete' code of the line : 'var model = //get model to update' ?

Comment: if u can paste code of your ActionResult that is rendering the form. i will be in better position to answer this question and plz edit this qustion to paste the code rather than using comments

Comment: Ok I have updated my initial post :) Hope it helps. BTW, thank you for your Help Muhammad.

Comment: ah i missed something. i forgot to mention to paste ActionResult which initially renders the page :(

Comment: Hey. I have updated the code I tried to realized in my original question : no compilation error... But no update. Seems like if a reload of my page is missing...

Comment: ITs now working. not fully however... The code is passing in my UpdateListProvidern server side code. I reload the structure to update in my model. The code is passing thru my client side part of my user control  UCProviders. My array is loaded. But when Im displaying my result, nothing appears... A problem of refresh ??

Comment: whatever you make an ajax (asynchronous call) the result comes back to your js and its your job to get the result and shove it in some DOM element on the page. it will not automatically show the response.

Comment: look at success function in my answer: i m just alerting some value you can get html back and put it in some div fon instance using $("#div1").html(data);

Comment: well. A strange thing happens... I cant see the generated code when Im watching the source of my generated page. In the solution I mentionned (to update the user control thru the server side) or if I send some html code to my page... (Using IE8) Even if in the second case, I see the result of my code on the page...